# How to add UIView to SCNPlane ARKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to show my uiview in arkit. But I couldn't figure out how can I show uiview in ARSceneView.

I tried this but its just crashing.

```
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNPlane(width: referenceImage.physicalSize.width, height: referenceImage.physicalSize.height))
        planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        planeNode.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = self.pieChartsView
node.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

What should I do for show my uiview in arkit ?

Comment: Where is the code for the pie chart view? :)

Comment: It's just uiview

Comment: What exactly is the crash?

Answer (score 0):

Put the code in the "renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval)" function inside a "DispatchQueue.main.async { }"

Assuming all the related uiview is OK indeed.